# MySQL many to many relation count

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of many to many relation, connecting two other tables, that I designed as such:

```
id
table1_id
table2_id
date_last_accessed
count
```

`count` is an `int` in which I intended to count the number of time this relation occurred, and so each time that this relation with the same `table1_id` *AND* `table2_id` occurs I will increase count.

However I see that a more common approach is to just make a bunch of these rows and count them when you read them.

Would you say one approach is better than the other? and why?

Comment: Usually you should prevent any duplication, so additional count column is not used. Sometimes you need to keep redundant information (de-normalize) to speed up some often used queries for example. In this case you need to make routines that update the info as robust/reliable as possible. The decision what should be DB design must be based on how you are going to use the data (what queries would be executed and how often)

Comment: I need to know the number of occurrences of this relation

Comment: Do you have 1000 or 1000M records? How often do you need to calculate it? How often data updated? Do you need to know this for ALL table1_id of for a limited set? Such questions should be answered first.

Comment: 100M.
All the time. 
All the time. 
Yes.

Comment: Why do you have multiple rows connecting the same pair of IDs? What distinguishes them?

Comment: One problem with trying to do this is that a trigger isn't allowed to update the same table. So you can't use triggers to keep the counts up to date, you need some other mechanism.

Comment: You could do it by putting the counts in a separate table that just has one row for each combination.